Definition of Fractional Sobolev Spaces by Fourier Transforms for $p \neq 2$
On the Wikipedia page for Sobolev spaces, Fractional (Bessel Potential) Sobolev spaces are defined with the following norm.
$$H^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n) = \{f \in S'(\mathbb{R}^n) \, :\, \mathscr{F}^{-1}\left[(1 + |\xi|^2)^{\frac{s}{2}} \mathscr{F}(f)\right]\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)\}$$ But, this does not make sense for $p > 2$. I would like to know if there is a way to somehow make this definition make sense for every $p > 2$, or do we just stick to the alternative difference quotient definition in those cases of $p$.

I removed the functional calculus tag, because the notion of functional calculus is exclusively (up to generalisations of course) used to define functions of a normal operator, i.e. new matrices like $p(M)$ for a matrix $M$ and a polynomial $p$, but for bigger classes of functions and for operators in infinite-dimensional spaces rather than just matrices. I do understand why people would use this tag for stuff functional-analysis and calculus related though.

You seem to be under two misconceptions:

This definition makes perfect sense for $p > 2$, as the Fourier transform, inverse Fourier transform and multiplication by a polynomial growth function of a tempered distribution are all well-defined as tempered distributions themselves. There might be an issue about whether the Fourier transform is bounded or not as a linear map though I guess (see for example: Why is the Fourier transform for $L^p$ not defined?)? However here you're just imposing that the final result be (a distribution induced by) an $L^p$ function.
There's sadly a problem with the "alternative" definition: it is only true for "$p = 2$" or for "$p$ any real but $s$ integer" that this definition gives you the same space as the one with derivatives and a difference quotient, though you do have inclusions at least (see for example the first chapter in Pierre Grisvard's Elliptic Problems in Nonsmooth Domains, or other references). I don't have counter-examples at the ready but you should be able to find one somewhere.

